# generate xml using xsd schema and output of a sql query

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a requirement in my Java application to generate XML based on XSD schema. Generated XML will contain data which will be returned by a SQL Query.
Any used library should be compatible with JBoss EAP6 and maybe older version.

Somebody suggested using Apache Xalan libs, but I can't find a good starting point.

Has anybody ever done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use JAXB api to create the xml output based on the output of the sql query. JAXB api is one of the J2EE standards and they are the most possible compatible api with many containers.

I didn't see your code, but I suggest the following solution:

You may use an ORM framework or just pure JDBC. After fetching data from DB to memory, you must hold them in some Bean like classes instances.

On the other hand, you should generate the mapping classes for your XSD. This is usually get done using JAXB commandline tools or IDE tools(Which utilize that command line tools in the background). I suggest to use Intellij-Idea or Eclipse JAXB tools.

Intellij:
For example if you have a CustomerOrders.xsd file, you can place it in a package and then by using right click on it, from webservices sub-menu, select "Generate java code from xml schema using JAXB...". Then a dialog will appear to select the output path and etc. You can see this in the following picture:

[image]

It doesn't matter which tool you use. Finally they would create one or more java classes for your XSD mapping. These classes must be stored in a package or folder which your code can access during the runtime. Then your only work is to convert your data holder bean instances to the instances of this generated classes. After that JAXB would marshal them into XML formatted String or Files as you order to through the api.

Sample code for using JAXB api could be like this:

```
try 
{
    CustomerType data = new CustomerType(); // This is a mapping class generated by jaxb tools.
                                            // You should convert your fetched data from DB to this type.
                                            // This object is the root object of your xml output file. 
                                            // Maybe you have some other child level classes under this object
                                            //    which creates your nested tags of your output xml data.
    Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance().createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); // this is for formatting the output xml data
    marshaller.marshal(data, new File("Wherever you want to save!"));
} 
catch (JAXBException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this would be helpful,

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks STaefi I will give it a try! 

Regards